# How to find "growing" files inside a linux system

Tags: linux, logging

I have a server that is constantly losing disk space so I reckon there must be some logs that I'm not aware of.

What is a good way to locate files that are constantly increasing in size?

Comment: You can write a script or use "watch" command for studying sizes of files

Comment: Have you checked logs (/var/log) and /tmp? For logs you should use logrotate to control their age and size. What's your partition layout? Good layout helps to narrow possible places, where such files are located.

Answer (score 15):

There is an utility called gt5 that displays current directory sizes as well as the difference from the last time you've checked.

Comment: Their homepage is here http://gt5.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 8):

you can use this command:

> find / -size +100000k

which will return all files having space more than 100 Mega Bytes. you can decrease or increase the value of size depending upon your need.

Or

You can use a utility called "ncdu" , which automatically creates a MAP of file/folder sizes.

Comment: This will only find the file if it's still associated with a directory entry - it won't find it if the file is deleted, but still open.

Comment: @Alnitak: i cannot understand what do you mean to say. please clarify.

Comment: I mean that if a file is opened, but then deleted whilst still open, it'll continue to consume space on disk, but will be invisible to `find`. The space will only be released when the file is closed.

Comment: tracking such files is something very different from question asked. it is possible to track those files as well, but with AuditD deamon.

Comment: This will also only display *large files*. It does not help in finding directories which keep growing by accumulating lots of small files over time for whatever reason.

Comment: @deceze: updated the answer with some additions

Answer (score 4):

Look at using the `ncdu` command ([available here](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu)) to give a nice summary view of directory size throughout the system. There are only a few common locations to check on a standard system for log files, so this should be easy to monitor. This is a good first step for discovery.

Long term, you should do one of the following...

Write a script to [search for files larger than a specific size](http://www.jarrodgoddard.com/linux-web-hosting/a-bash-script-to-find-large-files-on-a-linux-server).

The best approach, however, is probably log maintenance and rotation.

Answer (score 2):

---

There's a simple shell-script, it uses sqlite to store the data, so you can generate varios reports with it. Just add it to your crontab: `/root/bin/diskhogs.sh /directory/to/monitor`

The script itself is there:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Checking the spool directory
SPOOL="/var/spool/diskhogs"
if [ ! -e "${SPOOL}" ]; then
        mkdir -p "${SPOOL}"
fi
if [ ! -d "${SPOOL}" ]; then
        echo "There are no ${SPOOL} directory" >&2
        exit 1
fi

if [ -z "${1}" ]; then
        DIR=.
else
        DIR="${1}"
fi

FILES=$(find "${DIR}" -type f)

TIME=$(date +%s)
if [ -z "${TIME}" ]; then
        echo "Can't determine current time" >&2
        exit 1
fi

for FILE in ${FILES}; do

        SIZE=$(ls -nl ${FILE} | awk '{ print $5 }')
        if [ -z "${SIZE}" ]; then
                echo "Can't determine size of the ${FILE} file" >&2
                continue
        fi

        sqlite3 "${SPOOL}/db" "INSERT INTO sizes VALUES ('${FILE}', '${TIME}', '${SIZE}');"
        if [ ${?} -ne 0 ]; then
                continue
        fi

done

for PERIOD in 60 300 600 1800 3600 86400; do

        TIME_WAS=$((${TIME} - ${PERIOD}))

        (
                echo "*** Since $(date --date="@${TIME_WAS}") (${PERIOD} seconds ago) ***"
                sqlite3 \
                        "${SPOOL}/db" \
                        "SELECT MAX(size) - MIN(size) AS mm, name
                                FROM sizes
                                WHERE time >= '${TIME_WAS}'
                                GROUP BY name
                                ORDER BY mm
                        ;"
        ) > "${SPOOL}/report_${PERIOD}"

done
```

If you need to generate more custom report, you can use sqlite:

```
sqlite3 /var/spool/diskhogs/db "
    SELECT MAX(size) - MIN(size) as mm, name
        FROM sizes
        WHERE
            time >= '$(date --date='10 days ago' +%s)' AND
            name like '/var/lib/libvirt/images/%'
        GROUP BY name
        ORDER BY mm DESC
    ;"
```

If I have some ideas on how to improve it, I'll update it on GitHub: https://gist.github.com/melnik13/7ad33c57aa33742b9854

Answer (score 0):

I found this handy perl script somewhere years ago and have used it ever since. Works great every time :-)
The author(s) are listed at the top, I take no credit for this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# dur - Disk|Directory Usage Reporter
#       Perl utility to check disk space utilisation
#
# The utility displays the disk usage:
#    - total number of files
#    - top big files
#    - extra info: aging files, directories
#
# USAGE: dur [-d] [-Tn] directory
#   eg, dur /usr           # top 5 big files for /usr
#       dur -T5 /opt       # top 5 big files for /opt
#       dur -T10 /         # top 10 big files for /
#       dur -d /opt        # directory usage for /opt
#
#
# NOTES:
# It is highly recommended to use standard File::Find Perl module
# when trying to process each file from a deep directory structure. 
# Some folks are writting their own rutine based on find(1) in Perl. 
# This sometimes will be slower than File::Find so make sure you 
# test this before you will run it in live production systems.
#
# There are a lot of talks over File::Find and its memory consumption and
# how can you minimize that. Basically it very much depends. I found that
# File::Find is much faster in Solaris 10 with a target directory of +1mil
# files than any custom perl script calling find(1M).
#
# You will see a memory usage increase but the script will be faster. The
# deeper the directory is the more memory will use.
#
#  Example:
#   You can easily check how dur works against a big deep directory,
#   over +1mil files:
#
#   PID USERNAME  SIZE   RSS STATE  PRI NICE      TIME  CPU PROCESS/NLWP      
# 19667 sparvu    228M  219M sleep   20    0   0:01:36 8.6% dur/1
#
#
# SEE ALSO:
#  http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=325146
#  
#
# COPYRIGHT: Copyright (c) 2007 Stefan Parvu
#
# 10-Dec-2006    Stefan Parvu    First Version, nawk to perl
# 02-May-2007       "      "     Added top variable for big files
# 13-May-2007       "      "     Added dir_usage subroutine
# 19-May-2007       "      "     Added comments, Perl Best Practices

use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;
use Getopt::Std;
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);


###########
# Variables
###########
my %files = ();
my %dirs = ();
my @sorted;
$|=1;
my $size = 0;
my $mtime = 0;
my $current_time = 0;

############################
#  Process command line args
############################
usage() if (($#ARGV+1)==0);
usage() if defined $ARGV[0] and $ARGV[0] eq "-h";
getopts('dT:s:') or usage();
my $topN  = defined $main::opt_T ? $main::opt_T : 5;
my $dirFlag = defined $main::opt_d ? $main::opt_d : 0;
my $secs = defined $main::opt_s ? $main::opt_s : 0;


#########################################
# Usage        : find(\&fileCount, @ARGV)
# Purpose      : counts the number, 
#              : of bytes of each file
# Returns      : A hash with all files
# Parameters   : 
# Comments     : Used from File::Find
# See Also     : n/a
#########################################
sub fileCount {
    if (-f $_) {
        if ($secs != 0) {
            $mtime = (stat($_))[9];
            #if ($mtime  $secs) {
                $files{$File::Find::name} = -s;
            }
        }
        else {
            $files{$File::Find::name} = -s;
        }
    }
    $mtime = 0;
}




#########################################
# Usage        : find(\&fileCount, @ARGV)
# Purpose      : counts the number,
#              : of bytes
# Returns      : scalar variable, with
#              : total number of bytes
# Parameters   :
# Comments     : Used from File::Find 
# See Also     : n/a
#########################################
sub dirCount {
    if (-f) {
        $size += -s;
    }
}

#########################################
# Usage        : dir_usage()
# Purpose      : reports the directory
#              : usage
# Returns      : n/a
# Parameters   : @ARGV
# Comments     : Calls File::Find
# See Also     : dirCount()
#########################################
sub dir_usage() {
    my $target = $ARGV[0];

    print "Processing directories...\n";

    opendir(D, $target) or 
    die("Couldn't open $target for reading: $!\n");

    chdir "$target";
    foreach (readdir D) {
        next if $_ =~ /^\.\.?$/;
        next if (! -d $_);
        find (\&dirCount, "$_");
        $dirs{$_} = $size;
        $size = 0;
    }

    closedir(D);

    @sorted = sort {$dirs{$b}  $dirs{$a}} keys %dirs;
    foreach (@sorted) {
        printf "%6d MB => %s\n",$dirs{$_}/1048576,$_;
    }
    print "Total directories processed: " . keys(%dirs) . "\n";
}

#########################################
# Usage        : top_files()
# Purpose      : print top N big files
# Returns      : n/a
# Parameters   : @ARGV
# Comments     : Calls File::Find,
#              : default N=5
# See Also     : fileCount()
#########################################
sub top_files {

    print "Processing top $topN big files...\n";

#start counting here
    my $tstart = gettimeofday();

    find(\&fileCount, @ARGV);

    @sorted = sort {$files{$b}  $files{$a}} keys %files;
    splice @sorted, $topN if @sorted > $topN;

#print scalar %files;

    foreach (@sorted) {
        printf "%6d MB => %s\n", $files{$_}/1048576, $_;
    }

    my $tend = gettimeofday();
    my $elapsed = $tend - $tstart;

#end timing
    printf "%s %4.2f %s", "Elapsed:", $elapsed, "seconds\n";
    print "Total files processed: " . keys(%files) . "\n";
}


#########################################
# Usage        : usage()
# Purpose      : print usage and exit
# Returns      : n/a
# Parameters   : n/a
# Comments     : n/a
# See Also     : n/a
#########################################
sub usage {
    print STDERR /dev/null      # directory usage for /opt
    dur -s1200  /                # top 5 big files older than
                                 #  20 minutes for /
    dur -s86400 /                # top 5 big files older than
                                 #  1 day for /
END
    exit 1;
}


######
# Main
######
$current_time = time();

if ($#ARGV > 0) {
    usage();
} elsif ($dirFlag) {
    dir_usage();
} else { 
    top_files();
}
```

Comment: perl 5.12.4 doesn't like your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Has mentioned above `ncdu` tool is a very good tool and probably the best way to go.

But if you are under pressure and just want a quick and dirty way to find out what's going on. Just run the below from / (root)

```
    [root /]# cd /
    [root /]# du -sm * | sort -nr | head 
    3755    usr    
    151     var   
    109     boot  
    29      etc

    [root /]# cd usr  
    [root usr]# du -sm * | sort -nr | head  
    1618    share  
    1026    lib64  
    572     lib  
    237     bin

    [root usr]# cd share  
    [root share]# du -sm * | sort -nr | head  
    415     locale  
    255     icons  
    185     help  
    143     doc  
    [root share]# du -sm * | sort -nr | head   
    415     locale  
    255     icons   
    185     help   
    [root share]# cd locale  
    [root locale]# du -sm * | sort -nr | head   
    12      uk  
    12      de  
    [root locale]#
```

And so on and so forth to find and track down what directories and files are taken so much space.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little script `watch-open-files`, to watch open files that are changing and show their sizes growing. It could use some work, but it served its purpose of finding the growing files for me.

```
#!/bin/bash -eu
# watch-open-files: watch open files
lsof > open-files.txt
< open-files.txt txt2tsv > open-files.tsv
< open-files.tsv awk '$7 == "REG"' | kut 11  | uniqo |                                                                                       
grep -v -e '/proc' -e '/dev' -e '/usr/lib' -e '\.so\.' -e '\.so$' -e ' (deleted)' |                            
grep '^/' > interesting.txt
watch sh -c '< interesting.txt sortmtime 2>/dev/null | head -n 50 | kut 2 | xa ls -U -l'
```

At the moment, this script uses a bunch of other little tools:

- [watch-open-files](https://ucm.dev/b/watch-open-files): watch open files
- [txt2tsv](https://ucm.dev/b/txt2tsv): convert text to tab-separated values
- [kut](https://ucm.dev/b/kut): keep only the specified columns
- [uniqo](https://ucm.dev/b/uniqo): `uniqo' - like uniq, but it works on unsorted files, and preserves the order of lines
- [xa](https://ucm.dev/b/xa): xargs with a newline delimiter
- [kutc](https://ucm.dev/b/kutc): cut columns from a file
- [guess_columns](https://ucm.dev/b/guess_columns): guess the column positions of a file

I can possibly clean all this up into a single script if that would be better, and if someone else would like to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **tree**, which can be found in most distros provided by a package with the same name.

### Usage:

```
tree -h -x / > my_current_tree
```

- `-h` shows dimensions in a human readable way (Kilobytes, Megabytes, Gigabytes etc...)
- `-x` makes sure you only check the files on the given filesystem. If you run it on root `/` with this option, you won't get file sizes for other filesystems such as `/mnt`, `/proc` etc...

Wait some time, and run the command again, this time with a different name:

```
tree -h -x / > my_current_tree_$(date '+%+Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')
```

Then, run a diff on the 2 files to get the differences:

```
diff --suppress-common-lines --side-by-side my_current_tree*
```

This works well with a few big files but also with many, smaller files. Do keep an eye on your disk usage, a lot of files will result in a large output, in my case with ~221000 directories and ~1275000 files the resulting file was ~130 Megabytes.

### Example:

```
tree -h -x /path/to/growing/dir > my_current_tree_$(date '+%+Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')
```

Output (written in a file with name **my_current_tree_2024_02_28_16_03_22** in my case):

```
[ 120]  /path/to/growing_dir/
├── [ 10M]  growing_file_1
├── [ 10M]  static_file_1
├── [ 10M]  static_file_2
└── [  60]  subdir
    └── [ 10M]  growing_file_2

2 directories, 4 files
```

Wait some time... And run the command again:

```
tree -h -x /path/to/growing/dir > my_current_tree_$(date '+%+Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')
```

This time the output will be:

```
[ 120]  /path/to/growing/dir/
├── [ 20M]  growing_file_1
├── [ 10M]  static_file_1
├── [ 10M]  static_file_2
└── [  60]  subdir
    └── [ 30M]  growing_file_2

2 directories, 4 files
```

Running a diff:

```
diff --suppress-common-lines --side-by-side my_current_tree*
```

Will show us:

```
├── [ 10M]  growing_file_1                    | ├── [ 20M]  growing_file_1
    └── [ 10M]  growing_file_2                    |     └── [ 30M]  growing_file_2
```

You could also use **vimdiff** to get a nicely colored output:
[image: differences between the 2 files highlighted with colors]

Always [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)!